# Find all files inside a folder that do not contain a whitespace

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script that finds all the files inside of a directory that do not contain a whitespace, but I'm finding some difficulties. I'm using a combination of find and grep and it seems to work for everything but whitespace. I tried both:

```
find $d -name '*.js' | xargs grep -L '[ \t]*'
```

and

```
find $d -name '*.js' | xargs grep -L '[[:space:]]'
```

and both do not work. How can I correctly match the whitespaces?

EDIT: to clarify, I want to search inside the files, not in the file name.

Comment: You probably want `[ \t]+` for the first one; *every* file will contain the empty string, which `[ \t]*` matches.

Comment: How do these not work?

Comment: Are you looking for *files* that don't contain whitespace, or file *names*?

Comment: I want to search inside the files

Comment: @GianLucaScoccia thanks for the clarification. I've included some edits to better answer now.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/2g5Izg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f \( -exec grep -q '[[:space:]]' {} \; -o -print \)
```

When grep finds files with whitespace, it returns "success". If the command in `-exec` is successful, `find` allows the next predicate to operate; however, if the next operator is `-o` for "OR", then `find` only allows the next predicate to operate if the command in `-exec` is *not* successful. That's why the above works: It matches files that have whitespace, but then only prints out files whose names do *not* match. (The parentheses are necessary so the that `-type f` isn't also subject to the "or" – otherwise we'd get all things that are not *files*, like directory names.) You can limit it just to *.js files, if you like:

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' \
    \( -exec grep -q '[[:space:]]' {} \; -o -print \)
```

It's worth noting that `grep` is not a good tool if you want to detect *newlines*. For that, you might consider something brute-force:

```
for file in "$d"/*.js; do
    origcheck=$(md5sum < "$file")
    nospacecheck=$(tr -d '[:space:]' < "$file" | md5sum)
    [[ "$origcheck" = "$nospacecheck" ]] || printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

This creates a checksum of each matching file with, and without all of its whitespace. If the checksums are the same, the file never had any whitespace. (But many files end with a newline, so watch out.)

### Notes on the original approach:

The grep manpage on my computer says

```
-L … Only the names of files not containing selected lines are written…
     If the standard input is searched, the string ``(standard input)'' is written.
```

But [the standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) do not mention `-L`, so there is no guarantee that it behaves that way in other implementations. Here are some experiments:

Quick sanity check:

```
$ grep -L '[a]' <<< 'a'
$ grep -L '[a]' <<< 'b'
(standard input)
```

So far, so good.

```
$ grep -L '[ \t]' <<< 'ab c'
$ grep -L '[ \t]' <<< $'ab\tc'
(standard input)
```

(In bash, we can write literal characters like tabs and newlines with a special form of quoting that interprets backslash escapes. Here, `$'\t'` expands to a literal tab character.) So we see that the string with the space is a match, but the string with the literal tab is not a match.

```
$ grep -L '[ \t]' <<< t
$ grep -L '[ \t]' <<< '\'
$
```

The fact that a literal 't' is a match is evidence that the backslash-t is not a *tab* to grep. A literal backslash is a match, too, so it seems the expression is being taken by grep at face value. Well, we know one way to express a real tab:

```
$ grep -L $'[ \t]' <<< $'\t'
$ grep -L $'[ \t]' <<< 't'
(standard input)
$ grep -L $'[ \t]' <<< '\'
(standard input)
```

So the problem with the original expression was that we weren't looking for files that had no spaces or tabs: We were looking for files that had no spaces, backslash or 't' characters.

I avoided talking about `*` until now, but that matches zero or more characters, so even if you get the character class to match the right characters, following it with an asterisk will not get the results you want:

```
$ grep -L $'[ \t]*' <<< $'\t'
$ grep -L $'[ \t]*' <<< t
$
```

Do the above input strings have zero or more tab characters? Yes. Both of them do. You just want to find one character, so don't make it complicated.

#### But what about `[[:space:]]`?

```
$ grep -L '[[:space:]]' <<< ' '
$ grep -L '[[:space:]]' <<< $'\t'
$ grep -L '[[:space:]]' <<< x
(standard input)
```

Well, this one I can't explain. It all works as expected on both machines I tested it on (OS X and Linux). Perhaps you originally had an asterisk after '[[:space:]]'? I don't know. It's a mystery.

#### `find … | xargs`

Piping `find` to xargs can introduce problems itself. The shell does wordsplitting on argument names, and pipes like this can lose information about spaces in the actual filenames being passed. It's a rare enough case that many simply don't think or care about it, but it can and does happen, and it's not really hard to solve it.

First, `find` has `-exec`, so instead of

```
find . -some -predicate | xargs some command
```

you can simply write

```
find . -some -predicate -exec some command {} +
```

If, for some reason, you really want to use xargs (perhaps you want to take advantage of parallelization), then tell both find and xargs that filenames are to be delimited with the NUL character instead of space:

```
find . -some -predicate -print0 | xargs -0 some command
```

Comment: Good news is that it works and I'm going to flag it as accepted answer, bad news is that (with my limited bash skills) I have absolutely no idea on _how_ it works. Care to explain?

Comment: I see no improvement over the OP's original solution, and no attempt to explain how it might not work.

Comment: @tripleee Good call. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to simply exclude results (`-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines`, rather) which include whitespace from your `find` results...something like:

**Solution for finding filenames without whitespace**

```
find $d -name '*.js' | grep -v " "
```

seems to work great!

**Based on your edit**, the solution below should work for you, the results are only the files containing no whitespace content:

**Solution for finding files which contents contain no whitespace, (filename can contain whitespace in this solution.)**

```
find $d -name '*.js' |grep -iRlv " "
```

And I suppose a combination of the two could work, if you'd like to only return filenames which don't contain whitespace in addition to those files contents being free of whitespace:

```
find $d -name '*.js' |grep -iRlv " " | grep -v " "
```

Comment: This finds file names, not files, that don't contain whitespace (which, possibly, is what the OP wants.)

Comment: It's also ambiguous in that the existence (or not) of whitespace could be in the dirname, not the basename, or if part of the path contains a newline.

Comment: Added a solution for finding files as well, even if the filename may contain whitespace.

Comment: Also, needs more quotes. `find "$d"`, not `find $d`, or directory names with whitespaces or glob expressions will behave badly.

Comment: (Also, see comments on the question: OP has clarified that they care about whitespace in file contents, not file names).

Comment: I get 'grep: warning: recursive search of stdin'